# How to add contact information in a resume latex file?

Tags: resume

I am making a resumé in latex using the {res} document class. I want to add my contact information before the resume section starts, but now it inserts it as part of the resume section. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{\LARGE\textbf{NAME} \vspace*{.1in}}

\begin{resume}

% Contact Information
\begin{flushleft}
    \textit{Contact Information:} \\
    Address: 123 Street, City, Country \\
    Phone: (123) 456-7890 \\
    Email: your.email@example.com
\end{flushleft}

%   EDUCATION SECTION

\section{Education}
\textbf{University of Groningen}, Groningen
\vspace{0.2cm} \\ % SPACE
{\sl MSc}, Finance (2023 - 2024) \hfill Grade: 8.6
\vspace{0.1cm} \\ % SPACE
{\sl BSc}, Business Administration (2019 - 2022) \hfill Grade: 8.2
```

Comment: Where can we get `res.cls`?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{\LARGE\textbf{NAME} \vspace*{.1in}}

\begin{resume}

% Contact Information
\addvspace{1.5ex}
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{
\textit{Contact Information:}      \\
Address: 123 Street, City, Country \\
Phone: (123) 456-7890              \\
Email: your.email@example.com
}
\nointerlineskip
\addvspace{1.5ex}
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth}
%   EDUCATION SECTION

\section{Education}
\textbf{University of Groningen}, Groningen
\vspace{0.2cm} \\ % SPACE
{\sl MSc}, Finance (2023 - 2024) \hfill Grade: 8.6
\vspace{0.1cm} \\ % SPACE
{\sl BSc}, Business Administration (2019 - 2022) \hfill Grade: 8.2

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: @JochemV You can adopt my answer, thank you.